# FEM libraries with trace spaces

Tags: finite-element, libraries, discontinuous-galerkin

To implement hybridizable discontinuous Galerkin methods, one needs finite element spaces defined on the skeleton of the mesh. deal.II has support for HDG through FE_FaceQ class which provides discontinuous Lagrange functions supported on the skeleton of the mesh. I want to know if there are other libraries which provide such FE spaces for "embedded DG" (EDG) and "interior embedded DG" (IEDG) methods. EDG methods use continuous trace spaces while IEDG methods use trace space continuous on interior edges but discontinuous on boundary edges.